# SignatureDoesNotMatch when send request to amazon mws

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I want to send GetReport request to get the reports of the seller account.

But when I send it gives me signature does not match and I can't sort out what the problem is and stucked in this for several hours, I tried creating a signature and check the format of the request but didn't get through, the request on scratchpad is working fine.here's my below code

```
  check=(evt)=>{

    evt.preventDefault();

    let d=new Date();
    let reqDate=d.toISOString();

    let url='POST\nmws.amazonservices.com/\n'+'AWSAccessKeyId'=+accesskey+'&Action=GetReport'+'&Merchant='+sellerid
        +'&MWSAuthToken='+token+'&SignatureVersion=2'+'&Timestamp='+ reqDate +'&Version=2009-01-01'+'&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256'+'&ReportId=14941942615018036';

    let signature=base64.encode(SHA256(url,secretkey));


    agent
        .post(`https://mws.amazonservices.com/`)
        .query({
            AWSAccessKeyId:accesskey,
            Action:'GetReport',
            Merchant:sellerid,
            MWSAuthToken:token,
            SignatureVersion:2,
            Timestamp:reqDate,
            Version:'2009-01-01',
            Signature:signature,
            SignatureMethod:'HmacSHA256',
            ReportId:'14941942615018036'
        })
        .then(res=>(this.setState({category:res.text},()=>{
            console.log('category==>',this.state.category)
        })))


};
```

***REQUEST***:

This below request is made after above steps:

```
          Request URL:https://mws.amazonservices.com/?AWSAccessKeyId=accesskey&Action=GetReport&Merchant=sellerid&MWSAuthToken=token&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2019-05-22T09:19:15.213Z&Version=2009-01-01&Signature=ZWZiZjAxNGVlODZlYzc3NDlhYjljMmQ1NGI1NDNiZmY5N2VmMDIzY2YwMTdjNjgzYzkxM2MxMDllNzVjNzI1Mw==&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&ReportId=14941942615018036
```

when I send request above following request is generated in headers that Ihad mentioned in last,is there any problem in creating signature,or in encoding it in base64 or some other , kindly need suggestions

Comment: did you read the link I sent to you in the question you posted yesterday?

Comment: Yes I have read and by reading that I have reached to this code.I have completed the steps, but now the problem i think so is coming in this line:   let signature=base64.encode(SHA256(url,secretkey));